Maximizing with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
I want maximize the function $f(x)=\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x)$, with $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. By derivation $f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{6}$. But, if we write $f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ and  using  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, follows that
$u=(1,\frac{1}{2}))$ and $v=(\cos(x),\sin(2x))$ follows that
$$(1.\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x))^2\leq (1^2+(\frac{1}{2})^2)(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(2x))$$
We know that the equality occur if, and only if, the vectors $u$ e $v$ are parells, that is, there exits $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $1=t\cos(x)$ and $\frac{1}{2}=t\sin(2x)$. Therefore
$$\frac{1}{1/2}=\frac{t\cos(x)}{t\sin(2x)} \Rightarrow 2=\frac{1}{2\sin(x)} \Rightarrow \sin(x)=\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow x \neq \frac{\pi}{6}.$$
Does anyone have an explanation for this?

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
   \left(\cos x + \frac12 \sin 2x\right)^2 \le \left(1^2 + \left(\frac12\right)^2\right)\left(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 2x\right)
$$
is true, but it does not tell you where $f(x)$ is maximized. All it does is tell you that for all $x$, $$f(x)^2 \le \frac54(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 2x).$$ When $\sin x = \frac14$, the two sides are equal (they're both $\frac{375}{256}$, apparently, according to Mathematica). However, this has no reason to tell us the largest value of $f(x)$.
When $x = \frac\pi6$, $f(x) = \frac34 \sqrt3$, and $f(x)^2 = \frac{27}{16}$, and the right-hand side of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is bigger: it's $\frac{30}{16}$. Even though we don't have equality, the value of $f(x)$ is bigger.
In general, when maximizing $f(x)$, you want to apply Cauchy-Schwarz (or any other inequality you use) to get a constant upper bound. In the applications of Cauchy-Schwarz to trigonometric problems you may have seen before, we do this by getting $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$ on the right-hand side, which simplifies to $1$. But $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 2x$ does not simplify to $1$.
